# What are the irreducible representations of the $O(2)$ group?

Tags: symmetry, field-theory, gauge-theory, group-theory, representation-theory

I am currently working on the article "Non-Invertible Global Symmetries and Completeness of the Spectrum" ([arXiv:2104.07036](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.07036)), and in section 5.1 the author approaches the $O(2)$ gauge theory. In order to do this he says that the group has a $1$ dim irrep of determinant, and othe $2_q$ irrep related to the charge conjugation. I have had search all the internet looking for some reference of the irreducible representations of group $O(2)$  but I found nothing. Can someone help me to understand what is these representations?

Answer (score 2):

1. We can write the 2D [orthogonal
   group](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orthogonal_group)
   $$G~:=~O(2)~\equiv~\{M\in{\rm Mat}_{2\times 2}(\mathbb{R}) \mid M^tM={\bf
   1}_{2\times 2}\}$$
   as a [semidirect product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semidirect_product)
   $$O(2)~\cong~\mathbb{Z}_2\ltimes SO(2), \qquad \mathbb{Z}_2~\equiv~\{\pm
   1\}~\cong~\{{\bf 1}_{2\times 2},\sigma_3\}.$$
   The group isomorphism is
   $$M~\mapsto~ (\det(M), \sigma_3^{\frac{1-\det(M)}{2}}M) $$
   with inverse map
   $$ (d,M)~\mapsto~\sigma_3^{\frac{1-d}{2}}M.$$
   The composition is
   $$(d_1,M_1)\star
   (d_2,M_2)~=~(d_1d_2,~\sigma_3^{\frac{1-d_2}{2}}M_1\sigma_3^{\frac{1-d_2}{2}}
   M_2).$$
   The chosen element $\sigma_3\in O(2)$ corresponds to mirror reflection across the $x$-axis, which we will later identify with charge conjugation
   $$\sigma_3 M \sigma_3~=~M^t, \qquad M~\in~SO(2).$$
   Similarly $\sigma_1\in O(2)$ corresponds to mirror reflection across the $x=y$ diagonal.
2. The group of 2D rotations $SO(2)\cong e^{so(2)}$ is a [normal subgroup](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Normal_subgroup) with generator $i\sigma_2$, i.e.
   the corresponding abelian [Lie algebra](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lie_algebra) is
   $$so(2)~\cong~ \mathbb{R}i\sigma_2.$$
3. There is a group isomorphism
   $$H~:=~U(1)~\equiv~\{z\in\mathbb{C} \mid |z|=1\}~\cong~~SO(2)$$ given by
   $$U(1)~\ni~e^{i\theta} ~~\leftrightarrow~~e^{\theta i\sigma_2} ~=~\begin{pmatrix} \cos\theta &\sin\theta\cr
   -\sin\theta&\cos\theta\end{pmatrix}~\in~SO(2).$$
4. The [irreducible representations](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Irreducible_representation) (=irreps) of the abelian group $H=U(1)$ are 1-dimensional representations $1_q: U(1)\to U(1)$, labelled by an integer charge $q\in\mathbb{Z}$, and given as $$z~\stackrel{1_q}{\mapsto}~z^q~\leftrightarrow~M^q,
   \qquad z~\in~U(1), \qquad M~\in~SO(2).$$
5. The finite group $\mathbb{Z}_2$ has 2 irreps:

   - The trivial representation $$\mathbb{Z}_2~\stackrel{1}{\to}~1,$$
   - The identity map
     $$\mathbb{Z}_2~\stackrel{\rm id}{\to}~ \mathbb{Z}_2.$$
6. A group representation $\rho: G\to GL(n,\mathbb{C})$ (and its corresponding Lie algebra representation) must satisfy
   $$ C\rho(i\sigma_2)C
   ~=~-\rho(i\sigma_2), \qquad C^2={\bf 1}_{n\times n}, \qquad C~:=~\rho(\sigma_3).$$
   We may assume that $\rho(i\sigma_2)={\rm diag}(q_1,\ldots, q_n)$ is a diagonal matrix. Then
   $$  (q_j+q_k)C_{jk}~=~0,\qquad j,k~\in~\{1,\ldots, n\}. $$
   It follows that

   - $\forall j~\in~\{1,\ldots, n\}:~~C_{jj}~\neq~0~\Rightarrow~q_j~=~0$.
   - $\forall j,k~\in~\{1,\ldots, n\}:~~q_j+q_k~\neq~0~\Rightarrow~C_{jk}~=~0$.
   - If $n=1$ then $\rho(i\sigma_2)=0$.
   - If $n\geq 3$, then $\rho$ has a non-trivial $G$-invariant subspace, i.e. $\rho$ is not irreducible.
7. In conclusion, one may show that the group $G = O(2)$ has only 3 types of irreps:

   - The trivial representation $$G~\stackrel{1}{\to}~1,$$
   - The projection/determinant map $$\mathbb{Z}_2\ltimes SO(2)~\stackrel{1_{\det}}{\to}~\mathbb{Z}_2,$$
   - A representation $2_q:G\to GL(2,\mathbb{C})$, labelled by a positive integer charge $q\in\mathbb{N}$, and given by
     $$(d,e^{i\theta})~\stackrel{2_q}{\mapsto}~\sigma_1^{\frac{1-d}{2}}e^{iq\theta\sigma_3} .$$

   This answers OP's title question. The representation $2_{q=1}$ is isomorphic to the (complexified) defining representation of $O(2)$.

References:

1. B. Heidenreich, J. McNamara, M. Montero, M. Reece, T. Rudelius & I. Valenzuela, *Non-Invertible Global Symmetries and Completeness of the Spectrum,*  [arXiv:2104.07036](https://arxiv.org/abs/2104.07036)
   ; section 5.1 p.26.
2. Wu-Ki Tung, *Group theory in Physics;* Section 11.1. (Hat tip: [ZeroTheHero](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/36194/zerothehero).)

Comment: Notes for later: The [real irreps](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_representation) of $H$ are (i) the trivial representation $H\stackrel{1}{\to}1$ and (ii) $1_{q>0}$ under the identification $\mathbb{C}\cong\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

The good reference for this is

> Tung, W.K., 2003. Group Theory in Physics: An Introduction to Symmetry Principles, Group Representations, and Special Functions in Classical and Quantum Physics,

which has a section devoted to $O(2)$.

The irreps are constructed using the $SO(2)$ subgroup and the inversion transformation $I$.  There are two types of irreps.

Two 1-dimensional representations, with $so(2)$ label $m=0$, and inversion eigenvalue $\eta=\pm 1$:
$$
R(\theta) \vert 0;\eta\rangle = \vert 0;\eta\rangle \, ,\qquad
I\vert 0;\eta\rangle =\eta \vert 0;\eta\rangle
$$

An infinite number of $2$-dimensional representations, given in terms of the $so(2)$ label $m=1,2,3,\ldots $, with carrier space spanned by $\{\vert  m\rangle,\vert -m\rangle\}$, and with
$$
R(\theta)\vert \pm m\rangle=e^{\mp im\theta}\,\vert \pm m\rangle\, ,\qquad
I\vert \pm m\rangle = \vert \mp m\rangle\, .
$$

I'm guessing that in your context the inversion is equivalent to charge conjugation.